# Why is my route with two variables not working in my Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra app as follows:

```
get '/api/v1/:api_id/:init/' do
  @api_id = params[:api_id]
  @init = params[:init]

  @init_date = @init.split("-")      
  initial_date = Time.utc(@init_date[0], @init_date[1], @init_date[2]) # 2011-05-01 00:00:00 UTC  

  initial_date
end
```

When I browse to http://localhost:4567/api/v1/12345/2011-10-1/ I get "2011-10-1" and nothing can change that!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what do you want to get? Why should it be `2011-05-01 00:00:00 UTC`?

Comment: I just want to test it. It seems every time I change the "return" I have to restart the server?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your problem? Is that "have to restart server" or something with a date? If it's about restarting, read this - http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading

Comment: Do you mean that every time you change the code in your route you have to restart the server so that you see the new code take effect, and you want a way to have Sinatra automatically run the new code in your file? If not, what do you mean? Your only question is "What am I doing wrong?" but you have not shown anything that appears wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are easier ways to fetch your parameters and to parse a date:

   ```rb
   phrogz$ cat date_parse.rb 
   require 'sinatra'
   require 'date'
   get '/foo/bar/:id/:date' do |id,date|
     initial_date = Time.parse( date )
     initial_date.to_s
   end
   ```

   ```
   phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/foo/bar/42/2011-10-05
   2011-10-05 00:00:00 -0600

   phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/foo/bar/42/2011-11-1
   2011-11-01 00:00:00 -0600
   ```

   Does that not work for you? Every time you enter a different URL you get a different response based on the parameters in the hash.
2. Do you perhaps really want to use a `Date` instead of a `Time`?